# Why this gradient descent algorithm does not works for all values of sinus function?

Tags: python, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I have this gradient descent code that compute well for boolean functions but not for sinus. I do not know what is the problem with it? I tried to change activation function of hidden layer or output layer from sigmoid to hyperbolic tangent but it still does not compute the good values for some values of sinus.

Here is the Python code:

```
# L'algorithme de rétro-propagation du gradient dans un
# réseau de neurones avec 1 couche cachée.

# modifications par D. Mattei

from random import seed, uniform
seed(1789)     # si vous voulez avoir les mêmes tirages aléatoires à chaque exécution du fichier !
from math import exp, pow,pi , sin, tanh
from MatrixNumPy import MatrixNumPy
from time import time
import sys

# sigmoïde
def sig(x):

    try:
        s = 1/(1+ exp(-x))
    except OverflowError as e:
        # Somehow no exception is caught here...
        #print('OverflowError...')
        #print("x=",x)
        #sys.exit(1)
        s = 0
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
    return s

class ReseauRetroPropagation():
    
    def __init__(self,ne=2,nc=3,ns=1,nbiter=3,eta=1):
        '''Construit un réseau de neurones avec une couche cachée. Il y a ne entrées (+ biais),
        nc neurones dans la couche cachée (+ biais) et ns neurones en sortie.'''
    
        print(ne,'entrées(+1),',nc,'neurones cachés(+1) et',ns,'en sortie.')
        
        # le réseau calcule sur 7 vecteurs et 2 matrices
        self.z_i = ne * [0]     # les entrées concrètes seront fournies avec la méthode accepte
        
        # ne+1 in the matrix size because with add one column of bias in the matrix for each hidden neuron of the hidden layer "c"
        self.mat_ij = MatrixNumPy(lambda j,i: uniform(-1,1),nc,ne+1)  # self.mat_ij[j][i] == poids i->j
        
        self.z_j = nc * [0]     # valeurs z_j des neurones cachés
        self.grad_j = nc * [0]    # gradients locaux des neurones cachés

        # nc+1 in the matrix size because with add one column of bias in the matrix for each neuron of the output layer "k"
        self.mat_jk = MatrixNumPy(lambda k,j: uniform(-1,1),ns,nc+1)  # self.mat_jk[k][j] == poids j->k
        
        self.z_k = ns * [0]     # valeurs z_k des neurones de sortie
        self.grad_k = ns * [0]    # gradients locaux des neurones de sortie
        
        self.nbiter = nbiter
        self.eta = eta                  # "learning rate" 
        self.error = 0


        
    # fusionne accept et propage
    # z_* sans le coef. 1 constant
    def accepte_et_propage(self,Lentrees):         # on entre des entrées et on les propage
        
        if len(Lentrees) != len(self.z_i):
            raise ValueError("Mauvais nombre d'entrées !")
        
        self.z_i = Lentrees       # on ne touche pas au biais
        
        # propagation des entrées vers la sortie
        
        # calcul des stimuli reçus par la couche cachée à-partir des entrées

        # note: i just reference the variables for code readness (hide all the self keyword)
        mat_ij = self.mat_ij
        z_i = self.z_i

        # create a list with 1 in front
        z_i_1 = [1] + z_i
        
        z̃_j = mat_ij * z_i_1 # z̃_i = matrix * iterable (list here)

        # calcul des réponses des neurones cachés
        z_j = list(map(sig,z̃_j))
        #z_j = list(map(tanh,z̃_j))
            
        # calcul des stimuli reçus par la couche de sortie
        mat_jk = self.mat_jk

        # create a list with 1 in front
        z_j_1 = [1] + z_j
        
        z̃_k = mat_jk * z_j_1 # matrix * iterable (list here)

        # calcul des réponses de la couche de sortie
        z_k = list(map(sig,z̃_k))
        #z_k = list(map(tanh,z̃_k))
        
        # update the variable when necessary
        self.z_j = z_j
        self.z_k = z_k

        #print("accepte_et_propage : self.z_k ="); print(self.z_k)
        #return self.z_k               # et retour des sorties


    
    def apprentissage(self,Lexemples):  # apprentissage des poids par une liste d'exemples

        nbiter = self.nbiter

        ip = 0                          # numéro de l'exemple courant

        # TODO: take in account the error as stop point
        for it in range(nbiter):   # le nombre d'itérations est fixé !
            
            error = 0.0                     # l'erreur totale pour cet exemple
            
            (entrees,sorties_attendues) = Lexemples[ip]         # un nouvel exemple à apprendre
            
            # PROPAGATION VERS L'AVANT
            self.accepte_et_propage(entrees)       # sorties obtenues sur l'exemple courant, self.z_k et z_j sont mis à jour
              
            # RETRO_PROPAGATION VERS L'ARRIERE, EN DEUX TEMPS

            # note: i just reference the variables for code readness (hide all the self keyword)
            z_k = self.z_k # read-only variable
            grad_k = self.grad_k

            ns = len(z_k)
            
            # TEMPS 1. calcul des gradients locaux sur la couche k de sortie (les erreurs commises)
            for k in range(ns):
                grad_k[k] = sorties_attendues[k] - z_k[k]       # gradient sur un neurone de sortie (erreur locale)
                error += pow(grad_k[k],2)                              # l'erreur quadratique totale
                
            error *= 0.5
            #print(it)
            #print(error)
            if it == nbiter-1 : self.error = error                     # mémorisation de l'erreur totale à la dernière itération

            # modification des poids j->k
            mat_jk = self.mat_jk # read/write data

            z_i = self.z_i
            z_j = self.z_j
            nc = len(z_j)
            #eta = self.eta
            eta = ((0.0001 - 1.0) / nbiter) * it + 1.0
            #print(eta)
            
            # (test fait: modifier la matrice apres le calcul du gradient de la couche j , conclusion: ne change pas la convergence de l'algo)

            self.modification_des_poids(mat_jk,eta,z_j,z_k,grad_k)

            #print(mat_jk)
            
            # for k in range(ns): # line
            #     for j in range(nc): # column , parcours les colonnes de la ligne sauf le bias
            #         mat_jk[k][j+1] -= - eta * z_j[j] * z_k[k] * (1 - z_k[k]) * grad_k[k]
            #     # and update the bias
            #     mat_jk[k][0] -= - eta * 1.0 * z_k[k] * (1 - z_k[k]) * grad_k[k]
                                
            # Réponse à la question "b4" : T_{jk} = z_k * (1-z_k) * w_{jk}


            
            # TEMPS 2. calcul des gradients locaux sur la couche j cachée (rétro-propagation), sauf pour le bias constant
            grad_j = self.grad_j
            
            for j in range(nc):
                # must match the hidden activation function !
                grad_j[j] = sum(z_k[k] * (1 - z_k[k]) * mat_jk[k,j+1] * grad_k[k] for k in range(ns))
                #grad_j[j] = sum((1 - tanh(z_k[k])**2) * mat_jk[k,j+1] * grad_k[k] for k in range(ns))
                
            #print(grad_j)
            
            # modification des poids i->j
            mat_ij = self.mat_ij
             
            self.modification_des_poids(mat_ij,eta,z_i,z_j,grad_j)
            
            # for j in range(nc):  # line
                
            #     for i in range(ne): # column , parcours les colonnes de la ligne sauf le bias
            #         mat_ij[j][i+1] -= -eta * z_i[i] * z_j[j] * (1 - z_j[j]) * grad_j[j]
                    
            #     # and update the bias
            #     mat_ij[j][0] -= -eta * 1.0 * z_j[j] * (1 - z_j[j]) * grad_j[j]
                
                  
            # et l'on passe à l'exemple suivant
            
            ip = (ip + 1) % len(Lexemples)      # parcours des exemples en ordre circulaire


            
    def modification_des_poids(self,M_i_o,eta,z_input,z_output,grad_i_o):
        # the length of output and input layer with coeff. used for bias update             
        (len_layer_output, len_layer_input_plus1forBias) = M_i_o.dim()
        
        len_layer_input = len_layer_input_plus1forBias - 1

        
        for j in range(len_layer_output):  # line
            
            for i in range(len_layer_input): # column , parcours les colonnes de la ligne sauf le bias
                M_i_o[j,i+1] -= -eta * z_input[i] * z_output[j] * (1 - z_output[j]) * grad_i_o[j]

            # and update the bias
            M_i_o[j,0] -= -eta * 1.0 * z_output[j] * (1 - z_output[j]) * grad_i_o[j]
                

            
                
    def dump(self,n,msg):     # dump du réseau en entrant dans l'itération numéro n
        print('---------- DUMP',msg,'itération numéro',n)
        print('mat_ij :') ; print(self.mat_ij)
        print('z_j  :',self.z_j)
        print('grad_j :',self.grad_j)
        print('mat_jk :') ; print(self.mat_jk)
        print('z_k  :',self.z_k)
        print('grad_k :',self.grad_k)
        print()

    def test(self,Lexemples):
        print('Test des exemples :')
        for (entree,sortie_attendue) in Lexemples:
            self.accepte_et_propage(entree)
            print(entree,'-->',self.z_k,': on attendait',sortie_attendue)



            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
   
    print('################## NOT ##################')
    r1 = ReseauRetroPropagation(1,2,1,nbiter=10000,eta=0.5)
    Lexemples1 = [[[1],[0]],[[0],[1]]]
    START = time() ; r1.apprentissage(Lexemples1) ; END = time()
    r1.test(Lexemples1)
    print('APPRENTISSAGE sur {} itérations, time = {:.2f}s'.format(r1.nbiter,END-START))
    print()
    
    print('################## XOR ##################')
    r2 = ReseauRetroPropagation(2,3,1,nbiter=50000,eta=0.1)    # 2 entrées (+ bias), 3 neurones cachés (+ bias), 1 neurone en sortie
    Lexemples2 = [[[1,0],[1]], [[0,0],[0]], [[0,1],[1]], [[1,1],[0]]]
    START = time() ; r2.apprentissage(Lexemples2) ; END = time()
    print('APPRENTISSAGE sur {} itérations, time = {:.2f}s'.format(r2.nbiter,END-START))
    r2.test(Lexemples2)
    print("Error=") ; print(r2.error)
    #print("r2.mat_ij=",r2.mat_ij)
    #print("r2.mat_jk=",r2.mat_jk)



    print('################## SINUS ##################')
    r3 = ReseauRetroPropagation(1,50,1,nbiter=50000,eta=0.01)    # 2 entrées (+ bias), 3 couches de neurones cachés (+ bias), 1 neurone en sortie
    Llearning = [ [[x],[sin(x)]] for x in [ uniform(-pi,pi) for n in range(1000)] ]
    Ltest = [ [[x],[sin(x)]] for x in [ uniform(-pi/2,pi/2) for n in range(10)] ]
    START = time() ; r3.apprentissage(Llearning) ; END = time()
    print('APPRENTISSAGE sur {} itérations, time = {:.2f}s'.format(r3.nbiter,END-START))
    r3.test(Ltest)
    print("Error=") ; print(r3.error)
```

And the matrix class code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
MatrixNumPy.py
The class MatrixNumPy.
Derived from:
exo_mat2.py
La classe MatrixNumPy : algèbre des matrices de format quelconque, avec numpy
"""

# D. Mattei

from multimethod import multimethod

from typing import Union,Callable

from collections.abc import Iterable

import numpy


class MatError(Exception):     # juste pour la lisibilité des exceptions
    pass


Numeric = Union[float, int]



class MatrixNumPy:
    '''Construct an object MatrixNumPy.'''

    # >>> m1=MatrixNumPy(2,3)
    @multimethod
    def __init__(self,n : Numeric,p : Numeric): # lines, columns
        '''Construit un objet matrice de type MatrixNumPy, d'attributs le format self.dim
        et le tableau architecturé en liste de listes de même longueur. Exemples :
            m = MatrixNumPy([[1,3],[-2,4],[0,-1]])  à 3 lignes et 2 colonnes
            m = MatrixNumPy(lambda i,j: i+j,3,5)    à 3 lignes et 5 colonnes'''

        if __debug__:
            print("# MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy (Numeric,Numeric) #")

        self.__init__(lambda i,j: 0,n,p) # return a Zero matrix


   
    @multimethod
    def __init__(self,f : Callable,n : Numeric,p : Numeric):

        if __debug__:
            print("# MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy (function,Numeric,Numeric) #")

        self.A = numpy.array([[f(i,j) for j in range(p)] for i in range(n)])

    
    @multimethod
    def __init__(self,Af : list):  # la liste qui contient les éléments de matrice

        if __debug__:
            print("# MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy,list #")

        if any(map(lambda x:type(x) != list,Af)) :
            raise MatError('MatrixNumPy : on attend une liste de listes !')
        p = len(Af[0])
        if any(map(lambda x:len(x)!=p,Af)) :
            raise MatError('MatrixNumPy : on attend une liste de listes de même longueur !')
        self.A = numpy.array(Af)         # l'array qui contient les éléments de matrice
        


    @multimethod
    def __init__(self,Arr : numpy.ndarray):

        if __debug__:
            print("# MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy,numpy.ndarray #")

        self.A = Arr

        

    def dim(self):
        '''Retourne le format de la matrice courante.'''

        return self.A.shape

    

    # m1=MatrixNumPy(lambda i,j : i+j, 5,2)
    # # MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy (function,Numeric,Numeric) #
    # m1
    #       0.00          1.00
    #       1.00          2.00
    #       2.00          3.00
    #       3.00          4.00
    #       4.00          5.00
    # MatrixNumPy @ 0x105ae03d0 

    # print(m1)
    #       0.00          1.00
    #       1.00          2.00
    #       2.00          3.00
    #       3.00          4.00
    #       4.00          5.00
    def __repr__(self):
        '''Retourne une chaine formatée avec colonnes alignées représentant
        la matrice m.'''
        
        return self.__str__() + '\nMatrixNumPy @ {} \n'.format(hex(id(self)))
        


    # >>> print(m)
    def __str__(self):

        '''Retourne une chaine formatée avec colonnes alignées représentant
        la matrice m.'''

        return self.A.__str__()

    

    def __getitem__(self,i):        # pour pouvoir écrire m[i] pour la ligne i
        return self.A[i]            # et m[i][j] pour l'élément en ligne i et colonne j

    def __setitem__(self, i, data):
          self.A[i] = data

    def lig(self,i):                # m.lig(i) <==> m[i]
        '''Retourne la ligne i >= 0 de la matrice sous forme de liste plate.'''
        return self.A[i].tolist()

    def col(self,j):
        '''Retourne la colonne j >= 0 de la matrice sous forme de liste plate.'''
        (n,_) = self.dim()
        return [self.A[i][j] for i in range(n)]

    
    def __add__(self,m2):
        '''Retourne la somme de la matrice courante et d'une matrice m2
        de même format.'''
        (n,p) = self.dim()
        if m2.dim() != (n,p):
            raise MatError('mat_sum : Mauvais formats de matrices !')
        A = self.A ; A2 = m2.A
        AplusA2 = numpy.add(A,A2)
        return MatrixNumPy(AplusA2)
    

    def __sub__(self,m2):
        '''Retourne la différence entre la matrice courante et une matrice
        m2 de même format.'''
        return MatrixNumPy(numpy.substract(self.A,m2.A))


    def mul(self,k):
        '''Retourne le produit externe du nombre k par la matrice m.'''
        (n,p) = self.dim()
        return MatrixNumPy(lambda i,j : k*self.A[i][j],n,p)
    

    # R  : multiplicand
    # matrix multiplication by number
    
    @multimethod
    def __rmul__(self, m : Numeric): #  self is at RIGHT of multiplication operand : m * self
        '''Retourne le produit externe du nombre par la matrice'''
        if __debug__:
            print("MatrixNumPy.py : __rmul__(MatrixNumPy,Numeric)")

        return self.mul(m)
        
    
    def app(self,v):                           # v = [a,b,c,d]
        '''Retourne l'application de la matrice self au vecteur v vu comme une liste
        plate. Le résultat est aussi une liste plate.'''
        # transformation de la liste v en matrice uni-colonne
        mv = MatrixNumPy(list(map(lambda x:[x],v)))          # mv = [[a],[b],[c],[d]]
        # l'application n'est autre qu'un produit de matrices
        res = self * mv         # objet de type MatrixNumPy car produit de 2 matrices
        res = res.A             # objet de type Array
        # et on ré-aplatit la liste
        return list(map(lambda A:A[0],res))


    
    # R  : multiplicand
    # m1=MatrixNumPy(lambda i,j : i+j, 5,2)
    # # MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy (function,Numeric,Numeric) #
    # m1*(-2,-3.5)
    # MatrixNumPy.py : __mul__(MatrixNumPy,Iterable)
    # # MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy,list #
    # MatrixNumPy.py : __mul__(MatrixNumPy,MatrixNumPy)
    # # MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy (function,Numeric,Numeric) #
    # [-3.5, -9.0, -14.5, -20.0, -25.5]
    @multimethod
    def __mul__(self, R : Iterable): #  self is at LEFT of multiplication operand : self * R = MatrixNumPy * R, R is at Right

        if __debug__:
            print("MatrixNumPy.py : __mul__(MatrixNumPy,Iterable)")

        return self.app(R)
            

    
    # R  : multiplicand
    # matrix multiplication
    # m2=MatrixNumPy([[-2],[-3.5]])
    
    # m1*m2
    #     >>> m2
    # [[-2. ]
    #  [-3.5]]
    # MatrixNumPy @ 0x7f48a430ee10 

    # >>> m1*m2
    # MatrixNumPy.py : __mul__(MatrixNumPy,MatrixNumPy)
    # # MatrixNumPy constructor MatrixNumPy,numpy.ndarray #
    # [[ -3.5]
    #  [ -9. ]
    #  [-14.5]
    #  [-20. ]
    #  [-25.5]]
    #MatrixNumPy @ 0x7f48a4362590 
    @multimethod
    def __mul__(self, m2 : object): #  self is at LEFT of multiplication operand : self * m2 = MatrixNumPy * m2 = MatrixNumPy * MatrixNumPy, m2 is at Right of operator

        if __debug__:
            print("MatrixNumPy.py : __mul__(MatrixNumPy,MatrixNumPy)")

        (n1,p1) = self.dim()
        (n2,p2) = m2.dim()
        if p1 != n2 : raise MatError('Produit de matrices impossible !')
      
        # le produit aura pour format (n1,p2)
        #return MatrixNumPy(numpy.matmul(self.A,m2.A))
        return MatrixNumPy(self.A @ m2.A)
        
    # m1.A @ m2.A
    # array([[ -3.5],
    #        [ -9. ],
    #        [-14.5],
    #        [-20. ],
    #        [-25.5]])
```

Comment: Have you tried ReLU? Changing initialization of weights?

Comment: yes i tried tanh,ReLU,sigmoid modifying derivatives too according to activation function used it is even worse as result.Changing initial weights change nothing.

Comment: i finally find my errors: for sinus the good activation function is tanh , eta (step) is mainly too big, and i made the error that my derivative function was not in all version of code matching the  activation function

Comment: You can answer your own posted questions.

Comment: @Memristor yes i will post an answer with corrected version of code when i have written the final version

Answer (score 0):

problem was in the choosing of the activation function, that must for sinus be able to provide negative values too

here is a modified code:

```
# L'algorithme de rétro-propagation du gradient dans un
# réseau de neurones avec N couches cachées.

#  D. Mattei

# python3.7 -O exo_retropropagationNhidden_layers_matrix_sinus.py

from random import seed, uniform,randint
#seed(1789)     # si vous voulez avoir les mêmes tirages aléatoires à chaque exécution du fichier !
from math import exp, pow, pi, sin , tanh
from Matrix import Matrix
from time import time


# sigmoïde
def σ(x):
    return 1/(1+ exp(-x))


# not used
def σࠤ(z):
    return σ(z)*(1-σ(z))

# not used
def tanhࠤ(x):
    return 1 - tanh(x)**2

def der_tanh(x):
    return 1 - x**2

def der_σ(x):
    return x*(1-x)


class ReseauRetroPropagation():
    
    def __init__(self,nc=[2,3,1], nbiter=3, ηₛ=1.0 , ηₑ=0.0001 ,
                 activation_function_hidden_layer=tanh,
                 activation_function_output_layer=tanh,
                 activation_function_hidden_layer_derivative=der_tanh,
                 activation_function_output_layer_derivative=der_tanh):
        
        '''Construit un réseau de neurones avec une couche cachée. Il y a ne entrées (+ biais),
        nc neurones dans la couche cachée (+ biais) et ns neurones en sortie.'''

        lnc = len(nc) # the total of all layer including input, output and hidden layers
        
        # on crée le tableau des couches du réseau
        # >>> nc=[2,3,1]
        # >>> [ [0] * n for n in nc ]
        # [[0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0]]      
        self.z = [ [0] * n for n in nc ] # les entrées concrètes seront fournies avec la méthode accepte
               
        # nc[n] + 1 in the matrix size because we add one column of bias in the matrix for each hidden neuron of the hidden layer "c"

        # >>> M = [ Matrix( lambda j,i: uniform(-1,1) , nc[n+1] , nc[n] + 1 ) for n in range(len(nc)-1) ]
        # # Matrix constructor Matrix (function,Numeric,Numeric) #
        # # Matrix constructor Matrix (function,Numeric,Numeric) #
        # [[[ 0.30891168 -0.06324858 -0.77054504]
        #  [ 0.56467559  0.4090438  -0.6001032 ]
        #  [ 0.04621124 -0.4736403   0.52908111]]
        # Matrix @ 0x7f14c2dfa090 
        # , [[-0.17710618 -0.32836366 -0.81737218  0.65399886]]
        # Matrix @ 0x7f14c2d9bad0 
        # ]
  
        # >>> print(M[0])
        # [[ 0.0865122   0.48109634 -0.88726825]
        #  [-0.62196803 -0.02562076 -0.12770346]
        #  [-0.19076204 -0.38836422 -0.91260862]]
        
        # use with M[0][1][2]  notation
        #M[i][j][k] == poids k->j from layer i to layer i+1
        self.M = [ Matrix( lambda j,i: uniform(-1,1) , nc[n+1] , nc[n] + 1 )   for n in range(lnc - 1) ]
        # for n in range(lnc - 1):
        #     print("self.M[",n,"]=");print(self.M[n])

        # >>> ᐁ = [ [0] * n for n in nc ]
        # >>> ᐁ
        # [[0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0]]
        self.ᐁ = [ [0] * n for n in nc ]    # gradients locaux des neurones cachés et gradient sur la couche de sortie
        # ᐁ[0] is useless but keep same index with z
        
        self.nbiter = nbiter

        # "learning rate" 
        self.ηₛ = ηₛ
        self.ηₑ = ηₑ
        self.error = 0

        self.activation_function_hidden_layer = activation_function_hidden_layer
        self.activation_function_output_layer = activation_function_output_layer
        self.activation_function_hidden_layer_derivative = activation_function_hidden_layer_derivative
        self.activation_function_output_layer_derivative = activation_function_output_layer_derivative


    # forward propagation
    
    # fusionne accept et propage
    # z_* sans le coef. 1 constant pour le bias
    def accepte_et_propage(self,x):         # on entre des entrées et on les propage

        # note: i just reference the variables for code readness (hide all the self keyword)
        z = self.z
        M = self.M
        
        if len(x) != len(z[0]):
            raise ValueError("Mauvais nombre d'entrées !")
        
        z[0] = x       # on ne touche pas au biais
        self.z[0] = z[0]
        
        # propagation des entrées vers la sortie

        n = len(z)

        # hidden layers
        for i in range(n-2) :
            
            # calcul des stimuli reçus par la couche cachée d'indice i+1 à-partir de la précedente

            # create a list with 1 in front for the bias coefficient
            z_1 = [1] + z[i]
            
            z̃ = M[i] * z_1 # z̃ = matrix * iterable (list here)
            
            # calcul des réponses des neurones cachés
            #z[i+1] = list(map(σ,z̃))
            #z[i+1] = list(map(tanh,z̃))
            z[i+1] = list(map(self.activation_function_hidden_layer,z̃)) 

            # update the variable when necessary
            self.z[i+1] = z[i+1]

        # output layer
        i = i + 1

        # calcul des stimuli reçus par la couche cachée d'indice i+1 à-partir de la précedente

        # create a list with 1 in front for the bias coefficient
        z_1 = [1] + z[i]
        
        z̃ = M[i] * z_1 # z̃ = matrix * iterable (list here)
        
        # calcul des réponses des neurones de la couche de sortie
        z[i+1] = list(map(self.activation_function_output_layer,z̃)) 
        
        # update the variable when necessary
        self.z[i+1] = z[i+1]
        

        #print("accepte_et_propage : self.z[i+1] ="); print(self.z[i+1])
        #return self.z[i+1]              # et retour des sorties


    def print_matrix_elements(self,M):
        
        for e in M:
            print(e)

        print()
    
    def apprentissage(self,Lexemples):  # apprentissage des poids par une liste d'exemples

        nbiter = self.nbiter

        ip = 0                          # numéro de l'exemple courant

        # TODO: take in account the error as stop point
        for it in range(nbiter):   # le nombre d'itérations est fixé !

            error = 0.0                     # l'erreur totale pour cet exemple
            
            (x,y) = Lexemples[ip]         # un nouvel exemple à apprendre
                      
            # PROPAGATION VERS L'AVANT
            self.accepte_et_propage(x)       # sorties obtenues sur l'exemple courant, self.z_k et z_j sont mis à jour
              
            # RETRO_PROPAGATION VERS L'ARRIERE, EN DEUX TEMPS

            # note: i just use local reference for the variables for code readness (hide all the self keyword)
            z = self.z
            
            i = i_output_layer = len(z) - 1 # start at index i of the ouput layer

            ᐁ = self.ᐁ
            
            ns = len(z[i])
            
            # TEMPS 1. calcul des gradients locaux sur la couche k de sortie (les erreurs commises)
            for k in range(ns):
                ᐁ[i][k] = y[k] - z[i][k]       # gradient sur un neurone de sortie (erreur locale)
                error += pow(ᐁ[i][k],2)                              # l'erreur quadratique totale
                
            error *= 0.5
            
            if it == nbiter-1 : self.error = error                # mémorisation de l'erreur totale à la dernière itération

            # modification des poids de la matrice de transition de la derniére couche de neurones cachés à la couche de sortie
            M = self.M # read/write data

            # because i dislike self keyword in my mathematical expressions i recopy the variables
            ηₛ = self.ηₛ
            ηₑ = self.ηₑ
            
            η = ηₛ
                        
            #η = ((ηₑ - ηₛ) / nbiter) * it + ηₛ
            #print(η)
                    
            # (test fait: modifier la matrice apres le calcul du gradient de la couche j (maintenant i-1) , conclusion: ne change pas la convergence de l'algo)

            მzⳆმz̃ = self.activation_function_output_layer_derivative
            
            self.modification_des_poids(M[i-1],η,z[i-1],z[i],ᐁ[i],მzⳆმz̃)

            #self.print_matrix_elements(M)
            
                        
            # TEMPS 2. calcul des gradients locaux sur les couches cachées (rétro-propagation), sauf pour le bias constant

            მzⳆმz̃ = self.activation_function_hidden_layer_derivative

            for i in reversed(range(1,i_output_layer)) :

                nc = len(z[i])
                ns = len(z[i+1])
                for j in range(nc):
                    
                    ᐁ[i][j] = sum(მzⳆმz̃(z[i+1][k]) * M[i][k][j+1] * ᐁ[i+1][k] for k in range(ns))

                # modification des poids de la matrice de transition de la couche i-1 à i
         
                self.modification_des_poids(M[i-1],η,z[i-1],z[i],ᐁ[i],მzⳆმz̃)

            #self.print_matrix_elements(M)

            # et l'on passe à l'exemple suivant
            
            #ip = (ip + 1) % len(Lexemples)      # parcours des exemples en ordre circulaire
            ip = randint(0,len(Lexemples) - 1)
           

    

            
    # modify coefficients layer
    def modification_des_poids(self,M_i_o,η,z_input,z_output,ᐁ_i_o,მzⳆმz̃): # derivative of activation function of the layer
        # the length of output and input layer with coeff. used for bias update             
        (len_layer_output, len_layer_input_plus1forBias) = M_i_o.dim()
        
        len_layer_input = len_layer_input_plus1forBias - 1
       
        for j in range(len_layer_output):  # line
            
            for i in range(len_layer_input): # column , parcours les colonnes de la ligne sauf le bias

                M_i_o[j][i+1] -= -η * z_input[i] * მzⳆმz̃(z_output[j]) * ᐁ_i_o[j]

            # and update the bias
            M_i_o[j][0] -= -η * 1.0 * მzⳆმz̃(z_output[j]) * ᐁ_i_o[j]
                
            
                
    def dump(self,n,msg):     # dump du réseau en entrant dans l'itération numéro n
        print('---------- DUMP',msg,'itération numéro',n)
        print('M :') ; print(self.M)
        print('z  :',self.z)
        print('ᐁ :',self.ᐁ)
        print()

    def test(self,Lexemples):
        print('Test des exemples :')
        for (entree,sortie_attendue) in Lexemples:
            self.accepte_et_propage(entree)
            print(entree,'-->',self.z[len(self.z)-1],': on attendait',sortie_attendue)



            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    

    print('################## NOT ##################')
    r1 = ReseauRetroPropagation([1,2,1],50000,0.1,0.001,σ,σ,der_σ,der_σ)
    Lexemples1 = [[[1],[0]],[[0],[1]]]
    START = time() ; r1.apprentissage(Lexemples1) ; END = time()
    r1.test(Lexemples1)
    print('APPRENTISSAGE sur {} itérations, time = {:.2f}s'.format(r1.nbiter,END-START))
    print()
    print("Error=") ; print(r1.error)
    
    print('################## XOR ##################')
    # 2 entrées (+ bias), 1 neurone en sortie
    r2 = ReseauRetroPropagation([2,3,1],250000,0.1,0.001,σ,σ,der_σ,der_σ) 
    #r2 = ReseauRetroPropagation([2,8,10,7,1],50000,0.1,0.001,σ,σ,der_σ,der_σ) 
    Lexemples2 = [[[1,0],[1]], [[0,0],[0]], [[0,1],[1]], [[1,1],[0]]]
    START = time() ; r2.apprentissage(Lexemples2) ; END = time()
    print('APPRENTISSAGE sur {} itérations, time = {:.2f}s'.format(r2.nbiter,END-START))
    r2.test(Lexemples2)
    print("Error=") ; print(r2.error)
    #print("r2.mat_ij=",r2.mat_ij)

    print('################## SINUS ##################')
    r3 = ReseauRetroPropagation([1,30,30,30,1],50000,0.01,0.000001,tanh,tanh,der_tanh,der_tanh)
    #r3 = ReseauRetroPropagation([1,70,70,1],nbiter=50000,ηₛ=0.01,ηₑ=0.000001) 
    Llearning = [ [[x],[sin(x)]] for x in [ uniform(-pi,pi) for n in range(1000)] ]
    Ltest = [ [[x],[sin(x)]] for x in [ uniform(-pi/2,pi/2) for n in range(10)] ]
    START = time() ; r3.apprentissage(Llearning) ; END = time()
    print('APPRENTISSAGE sur {} itérations, time = {:.2f}s'.format(r3.nbiter,END-START))
    r3.test(Ltest)
    print("Error=") ; print(r3.error)
```

that give better result for negative values:

```
################## NOT ##################
Test des exemples :
[1] --> [0.01689504297821348] : on attendait [0]
[0] --> [0.9830944192099704] : on attendait [1]
APPRENTISSAGE sur 50000 itérations, time = 1.79s

Error=
0.00014274154026218158
################## XOR ##################
APPRENTISSAGE sur 250000 itérations, time = 10.37s
Test des exemples :
[1, 0] --> [0.9810061464215125] : on attendait [1]
[0, 0] --> [0.011947620311575518] : on attendait [0]
[0, 1] --> [0.9912776591389213] : on attendait [1]
[1, 1] --> [0.016587404568436263] : on attendait [0]
Error=
0.0001376149179875795
################## SINUS ##################
APPRENTISSAGE sur 50000 itérations, time = 91.43s
Test des exemples :
[0.3970408192667694] --> [0.39204110214399107] : on attendait [0.3866910553205351]
[-1.1259166520926764] --> [-0.9180159940389144] : on attendait [-0.9026624538345575]
[-1.5294358632424112] --> [-0.9745505222521297] : on attendait [-0.9991447779559608]
[-0.3149697338317652] --> [-0.31812446749796613] : on attendait [-0.3097876941225437]
[-0.956400033196182] --> [-0.8176127293472568] : on attendait [-0.8171216115916448]
[-1.4340677168359492] --> [-0.9739934966502118] : on attendait [-0.9906671967164332]
[-1.3386277357697225] --> [-0.9685255571082692] : on attendait [-0.9731697159094448]
[1.3521692785311998] --> [0.9685332263310458] : on attendait [0.976196148194918]
[0.8505988684180252] --> [0.7504636571410915] : on attendait [0.7516755134582983]
[-0.21874310457732649] --> [-0.2142122924254855] : on attendait [-0.21700284998872785]
Error=
8.610875421382934e-07
```